# error on top of home page

Tags: magento-1.9

i have just installed magento 1.9 along with a theme. but i keep getting this error message on the home page.

```
   <[!--{page/html_cookieNotice_global_cookie_notice}--]>  <[!--/{page/html_cookieNotice_global_cookie_notice}--]>
    <[!--{page/html_notices_global_notices}--]> 
<[!--/{page/html_notices_global_notices}--]> <[!--{page/html_header_header}--]>
```

then just below my navigation i get this message:

```
<[!--/{page/html_header_header}--]>
```

no other content renders on page.

But this error does not render on any other page except the home page.

can anyone please give me a tip on how to debug it or clear it

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue recently when updating to 1.9.4.0 and it turned out it was due to a php parse error we had in one of our custom modules (missing a closing parenthesis in our case).  Once we fixed the php code these messages disappeared.  You may want to enable php debugging for all levels of errors and watch your logs to see if you can isolate the issue.